# UpdatePanel postback causing blank space at top of page in IE 7

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, updatepanel

**(Edited the question's focus due to some more investigation)**

I have a simple page with a gridview inside an update panel. When I click the column header to sort, the postback fires and the sorting works, but a blank space appears at the top of the page, pushing everything down.

If I remove the UpdatePanel, things work fine and no blank space appears.

It doesn't happen in Firefox/Chrome, I only see the issue in IE 7 (or IE8/9 when Compatibility Mode is set to IE7 Standards).

So I'm wondering how to get around this, since users could still be using IE7 or have Compatibility mode on (quite a large and diverse user base on this system.) in a newer version of IE.

All I can see is that, on the async postback, this is added to the top of the form (first element in asp.net main form):

```
<DIV>
  <INPUT id="ctl00_ScriptManager1_HiddenField" type="hidden" name="ctl00_ScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="" />    
</DIV>
```

(IE tool is capitalizing)

I tried styling that input field but it didn't make a difference.

It's not a huge deal, but, if the UpdatePanel doesn't work properly, it makes me wonder what else will break in Compat Mode.

Thanks

Comment: Some times javascript (and on update panel a javascript update runs) add iframes or other divs on the page for do some background work. Maybe a frame like that is happens to you and its not the input that is all ready hiden anyway

Comment: Thanks - turns out it's a really old problem: http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2007/06/29/empty-div-takes-up-space-after-setting-innerhtml-to-blank.aspx - i'll work out a fix that works in my case and post an answer later..

Answer (score 4):

This is old but to all who are interested... Set the rendering mode of the update panel to inline. This can happen when you have empty update panels.